# Can I mix Ionic, Nodejs, MongoDB and Python to build a hybrid web application?

Tags: node.js, angular, python-3.x, mongodb, ionic4

I was decided to use Ionic as frondend, Nodejs as backend, MongoDB as DB and Python(for some machine learning purpose) to build an application. Is that possible that I use python in ionic to achieve some machine learning purpose ? I think about it for long time and I know that it is quite weird, because python is a language and Ionic is a web-framework.

My plan was to use Python to do machine learning for recommending staff for different type of user, Jupyter will also being use in this case. Next, I want the result to be send to the ionic and display to the user, it's like Python are use at middle of frontend and backend.

Can these being done ? Because I never heard about Python work with nodejs, and some combination like Python with Ionic. Can this be done ? or it is not even possible? Or Python can only work with django?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to achieve an app that is based on the `user behavior`.

Ionic is used to build Hybrid apps or PWA's that works on Windows, Android and IOS.

For the backend you can use `NodeJs`, and connect to database `mongoDB`.

Here you have two options to have some `machine learning` functionality:

- From your `NodeJs` backend connect `MongoDB` and then to your `Machine Learning` code made on `python`.
- Use python as backend and machine learning.

The only way that I know for running some `machine learning` code with `NodeJS` is [TensortFlow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js)

There will be a book that will be released soon [Introduction to machine learning with TensorFlow.js](https://land.asim.dev/tfjs).